# Is there a really good web resource on moving to Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

The documentation with the module itself is pretty thin, and just tends to point to MOP.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you should read through the [Manual](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual) if you haven't already. Then you can go on to read the [Cookbook](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Cookbook).

I think the docs are actually pretty good these days, as long as you read the right ones. You *really* shouldn't bother looking at most of the docs for any class name starting with "`Moose::Meta`" unless you're interested in Moose's introspection features. I've tried to make this more obvious in the Moose.pm docs, which as of 0.57 tell you to read the [Manual](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual) and [Cookbook](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Cookbook) first.

If you're coming from a background of doing Perl 5 OO "the old school way", I'd also suggest taking a look at the [`Moose::Manual::Unsweetened`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Unsweetened) document, which compares Moose to equivalent Perl 5 "by hand" code.

Comment: The documentation does seem to be better for 0.57, Dave. I'm going to look at Unsweetened tonight. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

http://moose.perl.org is a good central resource for all things Moose

Answer (score 7):

Once you read the docs Dave mentioned, if you have some insight on how it could have been more approachable or gotten you off on the right foot (or simply been easier to find), perhaps you would like to contribute that to the documentation.  The developers cannot really read the introductory documentation from a new user's point of view.  So file a bug report (with a patch maybe) against the documentation and/or discuss it on the mailing list or irc channel.  That will help the next person in your shoes.

Comment: I'll take some notes about my learning process, write something up, and submit them to Dave, if he finds them valuable, he can include them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [Moose Quick Reference sheet](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~oliver/data/files/moose-quick-ref.pdf) invaluable. I'm always forgetting in which manual section to look up a particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

I too am just starting to move on to Moose.  Since the term *good* can be rather subjective, I'll just detail what I found was good in these resources.  The resources may be more or less helpful depending on your skills/experience in Perl.

I started off at this [Perl Monks page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=702738).  And moved straight into the [Moose::Cookbok](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3A%3ACookbook) link listed at the bottom.  There, the author included several more links to pods demonstrating Moose syntax and object-oriented programs.  The ordering was put together well; starting with simple and basic OOP with Moose at the top, progressing to more complex examples as you go down the page.  The pods are well written, aren't overly wordy, and explain each chunk of the code clearly.

I'm sure once you're done with the Cookbook, you could check out whatever else was listed at the Perl Monks page.  I'm still going through the examples in the Cookbook, so I haven't checked all the resources listed at Perl Monks, but I'm sure they're good.